# How to add dynamic data in Autocomplete in Materialize.js

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, materialize

Jquery autocomplete is not working with materialize theme and autocomplete of materialize theme working with only static data

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data:
  {
    "Apple":null,
    "Google":null
  },
  limit: 20, 
  onAutocomplete: function(val) {
    alert(val);
  },
  // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
  minLength: 1,
});
```

This is the code, I'd like to know how can I add dynamic data through an ajax call?